# How to print the name of function passed as an argument?

Tags: c++

In the following code, I want  `Benckmark` to print the name of the functor passed into `Benchmark`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// You can only modify Benchmark
template<typename F>
void Benchmark(F f)
{
    f();

    // print the name to which f() refers.
 }

// A cannot be modified
void A(int x)
{

}

void main()
{
    int x = 1;
    Benchmark([&]() {A(x); }); // should only print "A" rather than "[&]() {A(x); }"
}
```

Comment: You aren't asking to print the name of the function passed into `Benchmark`, you are asking to print the name of a function **called** from *inside* a function passed to `Benchmark`. Very different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't *really* a way in C++ to do that sort of reflection (as of writing this, anyway). The best you can do is use a wrapper macro, which grabs the token sequence you pass, creates a string out of it, and passes it along with some more useful data to the *real* function.

```
#define Benchmark(...) BenchmarkImpl(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __LINE__)

template<typename F>
void BenchmarkImpl(F f, char const* name, char const* file, unsigned long long line)
{
    f();
    std::cout << "ran " << name << "(" << file << ", line " << line << " )"; 
}
```

Running the above code [on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eVUEpVfftzkeYxnK), prints:

```
ran [&]() {A(); } (prog.cc, line 19 )
```

Answer (score 4):

With MACRO, you might do something:

```
template<typename F>
void Benchmark(const char* name, F f)
{
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
    f();
}

#define BENCHMARK(f) Benchmark(#f, [](){ f; })

void A()
{
    // 
}

int main()
{
    BENCHMARK(A());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding trimming stuff to @TellStory's answer.

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define Benchmark(...) BenchmarkImpl(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)

template<typename F>
void BenchmarkImpl(F f, char const* name)
{
    const string input = name;
    const regex regex("\\{\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\\(");
    smatch match;
    string output = "defaultName";
    if (regex_search(input, match, regex))
        output = match.str(1);

    f();

    cout << "Function name: " << output << endl;
}
void Ab1(int x)
{
    //
}
int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    Benchmark([&]() {   Ab1   (x); });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

C++ does not have a type reflection, but there is a work around. Not elegant but works.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*FunctionType)();

template<typename F>
void Benchmark(F f)
{
    f();
}

#define BENCHMARKTEST(F, f) \
cout << "Benchmark test for:" << #f << endl; \
Benchmark<F>(f);

void funcToBeTest()
{
}

int main()
{
    BENCHMARKTEST(FunctionType, funcToBeTest);

    return 0;
}
```